# How do I remove a site when the remove-spsite returns "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: site-collection

I have a 2010 SharePoint farm with 5 site collections.  Because we're using TFS with multiple team project collections in the 2010 farm, I need to take a phased migration approach to move the content from the 2010 farm to the 2013 farm.

Because we're taking a phased migration approach, we will need to upgrade the content several times.  SharePoint 2013 won't allow me to upgrade a site collection more than once.  If I do, I get this error:

```
Site <url> cannot be upgraded
```

I get this error because the site collection's GUID exists in the database.  It exists even if I delete the site collection in `Central Administration`.

A bit of googling suggests that I should use PowerShell to do this.  So I attempted to do that:

```
remove-spsite -identity "<guid>"
```

returns the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

More googling suggests using a [force option to delete](http://blog.claudiobrotto.com/2013/deleting-a-site-collection-that-cannot-be-deleted/).  It fails with the same error.

If I query the `SiteMap` table in the `SharePoint_Config` database, I can see the GUID for the site in this table, but I'm reluctant to delete it using SQL for fear that I may create more orphans in the database.

Does anyone know how to fix this using a Microsoft released utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even more googling found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9d41267-1d52-40f9-8b63-1c84cd151e3b/databaseattach-upgrade-failing-with-nullreference-exception-sql-errors-occuring-at-about-the?forum=sharepointadminprevious), which suggests using [`STSADM`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288016(v=office.12).aspx) from an elevated command prompt.

By default, STSADM can be found here:

```
c:\> cd\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\
> STSADM -o deletesite -force -siteid "<GUID>" -databasename "<ContentDatabaseName>" -databaseserver "<ContentDatabaseServer>"
```